# Format.js and render json combined in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, render

I need to pass json object and format.js from a Rails controller.. 
if I do

```
    respond_to do |format|
     format.js 
    end
```

I get the javascript file (controllername.js) to run. If I do

```
    respond_to do |format|
     format.js {render json: @thing} 
    end
```

I get the json..

Is there a way to get both?

Answer (score 3):

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @thing }
  format.js
end
```

it will respond both depending on the request.

Comment: yep, failed for me as well